# Python: calculate the percentage of concordance between 2 lists?

Tags: python

Suppose I have 2 Python lists `x` and `y` with same length `N`.

Concordance is defined as, if `x_i` > `x_j` so `y_i` > `y_j`.

For instance, if `x` is a list of the grade of students and `y` is a list of their salary after graduation, concordance means a student A has score > a student B --> A will earn more than B (and vice versa).

How could I calculate (in an efficient way) the percentage of concordance between 2 lists (in total there are `N*(N-1)/2` pairs)?

**Adding example:**

Consider 2 lists:

x = 2,3,1
y = 1,2,3

x0 < x1 and y0 < y1: concordance_count += 1

x0 > x2 and y0 < y2: concordance_count += 0

x1 > x2 and y1 < y2: concordance_count += 0

So in the end, the concordance percentage = 1/3

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to find the combinations possible for both x and y

```
>>> from itertools import combinations                 
>>> x
[2, 3, 1]
>>> y
[1, 2, 3]
>>> combinations(x,2)
<itertools.combinations object at 0x1010482b8>
>>> combinations(y,2)
<itertools.combinations object at 0x101048208>
>>> list(combinations(x,2))
[(2, 3), (2, 1), (3, 1)]
>>> list(combinations(y,2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

And then find `a<b` for all values in the above list/iterator

```
>>> ["a<b" if a<b else "a>b" for a,b in combinations(x,2)]
['a<b', 'a>b', 'a>b']
>>> ["a<b" if a<b else "a>b" for a,b in combinations(y,2)]
['a<b', 'a<b', 'a<b']
```

And then [zip](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip) them.

> This function returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains
>   the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables.

Note: This is assuming that both `x` and `y` are of same length. If not, use `izip_longest` of `itertools`

```
>>> zip(["a<b" if a<b else "a>b" for a,b in combinations(x,2)],["a<b" if a<b else "a>b" for a,b in combinations(y,2)])
[('a<b', 'a<b'), ('a>b', 'a<b'), ('a>b', 'a<b')]
```

And then, find the concordance_count

```
>>> [1 if v1==v2 else 0 for v1,v2 in zip(('a<b' if a<b else "a>b" for a,b in combinations(x,2)), ('a<b' if a<b else "a>b" for a,b in combinations(y,2)))]
[1, 0, 0]
>>> concordance_count = sum(1 if v1==v2 else 0 for v1,v2 in zip(('a<b' if a<b else "a>b" for a,b in combinations(x,2)), ('a<b' if a<b else "a>b" for a,b in combinations(y,2))))
>>> concordance_count
1
>>> concordance_percentage = concordance_count/max(len(x),len(y))
>>> concordance_percentage
1/3
```